# Haskell where clause syntax inside a do block

Tags: haskell, syntax, where-clause

I am trying to refactor a `mapM_` function call inside a `do` block in Haskell. I would like to extract the lambda to a (locally) named function to make the code more readable.

My code originally looks like this:

```
do
  -- ...
  mapM_ (\x -> x + 1) aList

  return aValue
```

I would like to change it to

```
do
  -- ...
  mapM_ func aList
    where func x = x + 1

  return aValue
```

but I am getting a syntax error on the `return aValue` line. My actual lambda is more complicated :-), but I did try it with this same lambda to make sure it was not an issue in the lambda code.

How can I rewrite this code? Should I use `let` ... `in` instead?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are three similar (but distinct) ways of defining stuff here:

- You can attach `where` clauses after certain definitions--mostly equation-style bindings. So you could put one at the end of your function, or after something defined with `let` or a surrounding `where` clause.
- On the other hand, `let x = ... in ...` is an *expression* that evaluates to the part after `in`, which is the only place the stuff after `let` is visible.
- Inside a `do` block, because there's already an implicit nesting of scope (things are visible after they're first defined), you can use just `let x = ...` alone. This is really the same thing as the previous form--the rest of the `do` block after the `let` is effectively the `in ...` portion.

If you want a local definition that uses something defined within the `do` block, your only choice is the third (or passing the other value(s) as argument(s)). For an independent helper functions like your example, however, any style works. Here's your example, to demonstrate each:

The first style, where `func` is visible anywhere in `foo`, including anything else defined in the `where` clause:

```
foo = do ...
         mapM_ func aList
         ...
         return aValue
  where func x = x + 1
```

The second style, where `func` is only visible inside the `let` expression, which in this case is the entire `do` block:

```
foo = let func x = x + 1 
      in do 
         ...
         mapM_ func aList
         ...
         return aValue
```

And the third style, defining it inside the `do` block. In this case, `func` is only visible after the `let`; in the first `...` it hasn't been defined yet.

```
foo = do ...
         let func x = x + 1
         mapM_ func aList
         ...
         return aValue
```

Oh, and for good measure: Since `let ... in ...` is an expression, you can also use it anywhere you have an expression, to name some local definitions. So here's another example:

```
foo = do ...
         let func x = x + 1 in mapM_ func aList
         ...
         return aValue
```

As before, `func` is only visible inside the `let` expression, which in this case is the single expression after it, nowhere else.

Comment: Thanks. The third form looks like it will allow me to define the lambda function close enough to the `mapM_` to be useful. I'm only worried that it pollutes the top-level function namespace with the name `func` defined in the `let` (minor issue).

Comment: @Ralph: Well, it's just a matter of what scope you want it visible in. If your `do` block is big enough that you need to worry about polluting the namespace inside it, you should probably consider breaking it into smaller pieces anyway. :]

Comment: Yeah, that had occurred to me too. I'm translating some functional Scala code that some idiot wrote (:-)) with functions that are longer than they should be.

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to use `forM_` instead of `mapM_`, which flips the order of the arguments. You can then use the `$` operator with a trailing lambda expression like this:

```
do
  forM_ aList $ \x -> do
    ...

  return aValue
```

Comment: I had not considered that alternative. I'll look at my code again to see if that is more readable. In other cases where I need a monadic list traversal, but there is no convenient flipped version like `forM_`, I can just use `flip` to make a new function.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't your `where` be at the end of the function?

Like this:

```
function aList aValue = do
    mapM_ func aList
    return aValue
    where func x = x + 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure. I would like to find some way to extract the lambda into a very local function for improved readability. If I have to put it at the end of the top-level function, that makes it much less usable. I'm a Haskell noob.