# Error using where clause in let statement

Tags: haskell

Here's my code:

```
main = do
   contents <- getContents 
   let threes = groupsOf 3 (map read $ lines contents)
      where groupsOf 0 _ = []
            groupsOf _ [] = []
            groupsOf n xs = take n xs : groupsOf n (drop n xs)
    putStrLn $ show threes
```

When I run this while piping a text file into the input I get:

```
test.hs:4:13: parse error on input `groupsOf'
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. From what I can tell my syntax is correct...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell where clause syntax inside a do block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092801/haskell-where-clause-syntax-inside-a-do-block)

Answer (score 2):

You presented lots of syntax issues.

```
contents = <- getContents
```

That is invalid and should be `contents <- getContents`.

```
let threes = groupsOf 3 (map read $ lines contents)
   where groupsOf 0 _ = []
```

You can't have `where` after a let clause without further indentation.  You could either move the `where` clause to after the function,\ declare `groupsOf` in a let clause, or indent the `where` a little past the indentation of the variables in the let clause:

```
let threes = groupsOf 3 (map read $ lines contents)
    groupsOf 0 _ = []
    groupsOf _ [] = []
    groupsOf n xs = take n xs : groupsOf n (drop n xs)
```

Edit: And after referring to the Haskell 2010 report, I don't think `let { decls } where {decls}` is actually valid Haskell.  GHC parses the expressions, which I think is legitimate and nice in some situations although bad style here.